# __sync_fetch_and_or on gcc4.3 for Arm946

Tags: c, gcc, arm, atomic

I try to set GPIO pins on an Arm946. For this, I need an atomic access to a hardware address. __sync_fetch_and_or would do the job if it were available.
But compiling

```
(void) __sync_fetch_and_or(gpioOutReg, gpioPortPin);
```

gives a linker error

> undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_or_4'

which probably indicates, that my gcc 4.3.0 does not support atomic operations (I am passing the correct architecture and tuning hints with

> arm-ecos-elf-gcc (...) -march=armv5te -mtune=arm946e-s (...)

Do I miss another compiler/linker option? Is there some other way to atomically set/clear individual bits or is there some publically available library with a correct asm("...") implementation of the job? A mutex or disabling all interrupts around read/modify/write-code looks like a performance killer so I still hesitate to go along this line.

Comment: Use a modern compiler which supports C11 (gcc since 4.9, since 4.7 with external library) and use `stdatomics`. If you insist on the old compilers: see the documentation. Note: such operations on peripheral registers will not work as expected. In general, you have to exclude all other accesses. Neither `stdatomics` nor the gcc-specific builtins guarantee this. Even worse, they might loop multiple times.

Comment: I can't simply change the tool-chain as this would mean changing a whole bunch of existing code in quite a few projects and a lot of code. That is simply no option. The documentation does not say anything about specific targets, that is part of my problem with gcc. Or I am looking at the wrong places.

Comment: gcc documentations contains sections for each supported architecture. Did you link libgcc?

Comment: Option -nostdlib is passed, so I am probably not linking libgcc. That explains the linker error - the compiler tries to pass the atomic stuff to an emulation of atomic functions. Probably we do not use libgcc as we have ecos in the project, which brings a lot of symbols which probably collide with libgcc. Sigh. Probably returning to disabling interrupts.

Comment: Yes, you have to link `libgcc` manually. Remember gcc mght call other functio9ns, too (e.g. `memset`, `memcpy`, etc.).